# Swift: How to move button position that added in Storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I have added one button into one UIViewController in storyboard. Now I just want to try how can I move the origin x and y of that button from code so I write this code below

```
    @IBOutlet weak var testBtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    testBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 10)

}
```

but The button not move. Do you know why?

Comment: It's probably because you're running that code too soon. Try implementing `viewDidAppear:` and put your button-moving code into that.

Comment: @matt I thought the outlets are already connected in `viewDidLoad`, so the example from above should work

Comment: Did you connect your outlets? Do you use AutoLayout?

Comment: @MariusFanu The outlets are connected, but the views are not yet laid out (this happens just before `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`), so @matt is probably right (given that autolayout is enabled)

Comment: @Alladinian that makes sense, I looked the lifecycle of a VC 
loadView -> viewDidLoad -> viewWillAppear
-> viewWillLayoutSubviews -> viewDidLayoutSubviews -> viewDidAppear. So those frame are probably overwritten.

Comment: @matt is right, viewDidAppear is what you are searching for I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place it in viewDidAppear. Even viewWillLoad if not late enough.. Here is a good way to set it with little hassle:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Put the coordinates you want instead of x: 0, y: 0
    testBtn.center = CGPointMake(0, 0)
}
```

Remember that if you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation as recommended in the apple documentation. While not obligatory, it should relieve many problems ;)

Comment: No need to, it's standard declaration

Comment: Instead, you could simply do an edit on the answer... And you can take the down vote out now, it's rectified :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for fixing that. Very important to set a good example for beginners.

Comment: It is not obligatory as it is an override call. If you want to eliminate default behaviour from viewDidAppear, you would not call super.viewDidAppear on it now would you..

Comment: It is obligatory _because_ it is an override call. Read carefully. Say the words one at a time. "If you _override_ this method, you _must_ call `super`." That is Apple talking. Obey!

Comment: while it is not necessary to call super when overriding functions in general, in this particular case documentation explicitly states to call super when overriding viewDidAppear, therefor it is obligatory in the case of this function.  Not calling super could cause your app to miss behave.